# Thermodynamics Chain Rule And Independent Variables

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, differentiation, notation

I was reading my textbook and I came up across the entropy $S(T,V,N)$ where temperature $T$, volume $V$, and number of particles $N$ are the independent variables. According to the chain rule the total differential of the entropy in this case is :
$$dS=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N}dT + \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{T,N}dV + \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}\right)_{T,V}dN.$$
Then my textbook proceeds to evaluate $\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N}$ as
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N}=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_{V,N}\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N}$$
and then also inserts the result $\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_{V,N}=\frac{1}{T}$ from when $E$, $N$, and $V$ are the independent variables not $T$, $N$ and $V$.

Is this mathematically correct/legal?

Comment: Yes, it is correct (but as usual in thermodynamics, this is the abuse of notation hell). An easy way to see this is, as $V,N$ are held fixed in all expressions, to consider $S$ on the LHS only as a function of $T$, on the RHS only as a function of $E$ and $E$ only as a function of $T$. Doing so then is just the application of the "ordinary" chain rule, as all partial derivatives are "ordinary" derivatives.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I agree with your explanation, but what notation would you propose instead?

Comment: @Themis Well, for example we could write $\mathcal S:\mathbb R^3\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ with $(E,V,N) \mapsto \mathcal S(E,V,N)=S$ and $\mathfrak S: \mathbb R^3\longrightarrow  \mathbb R$ with $(T,V,N)\mapsto \mathfrak S(T,V,N) = S$ for the entropy. In other words, we obtain the entropy of the system $S$ through the two functions $\mathcal S$ and $\mathfrak S$. Obviously, if $\mathcal E:\mathbb R^3\longrightarrow \mathbb R^3$ with $(T,V,N) \mapsto (E,V,N)$ then $\mathfrak S = \mathcal S \circ \mathcal E$. Now the notation is not as ambiguous as before, but much more cumbersome.

Comment: Moreover, we shouldn't write something like $\partial_T$ but e.g. $\partial_1$ instead, i.e. we take the derivative with respect to the first "entry" of the function. In my experience something like $\partial_T$ also causes some confusion at some points. See also the [related] question by the OP and the discussion below an answer. It is important to distinguish the several functions which all yield the same physical quantity (e.g. the entropy). As I tried to explain, this reduces the potential confusion regarding derivatives etc., but of course is more "notational work".

Comment: @Themis Regarding the issue in the question. The derivative in the question can then be written as: $(\partial_1 \mathfrak S)(T,V,N) = \partial_1 (\mathcal S \circ \mathcal E)(T,V,N) =  \partial_1 \mathcal S(\mathcal E(T,V,N)) \, \partial_1 \mathcal E(T,V,N)$, where we've used the chain rule. See also excellent [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/577669/partial-derivatives-when-the-functions-inputs-are-dependent-on-the-same-variabl/577685#577685) to a related question.

Comment: @TobiasFünke As you say, it is cumbersome. Personally, I don't find the standard notation bad. And when it comes to thermodynamics, the simpler the notation the easier  is to convey the concepts.

Comment: @Themis I understand your point of view and I mostly agree. But IMHO, one should first write down everything explicitly and only then one can abuse the notation in order to ease it! Many books/lectures fail here, which quite often leads to confusion, in my experience.